# stackexchange.com profiles don't onebox

Tags: bug, chat, stackexchange.com, network-profile, onebox

Profiles from stackexchange.com (the 'main site' for the meta here) don't one box when posted into chat.

See, for example, [this message](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/4198371#4198371) from the tavern (I figured if the onebox was going to work anywhere, it would work there).

> [image]

The ***meta*** profiles work, but not the network-esque ones, such as those that you find linked from on https://stackexchange.com/about/team

Comment: And who said they should? The network profiles have a different structure, different code would be needed to one box them. It's just not implemented.

Comment: @nicael Its just that it is surprising that the links from the about/team from StackExchange.com, which ***look*** like they are regular profiles don't one box in chat. Yes, they are ***network*** profiles, but that functionality is a bit surprising as to why there is this one non-obvious exception at first glance. Especially when they are linked from a prominent page.

Answer (score 7):

While we wait for this bug/feature-request to be fixed/added, I've made a plugin for my [Custom Oneboxes userscipt](https://stackapps.com/q/6642/26088).

It uses the API to get the username, about me, profile picture, etc... and makes [it look pretty](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/4198474#4198474):

[image]

### To use it...

1. Install the [userscript](https://stackapps.com/q/6642/26088)
2. Copy and paste the below code just above the `--------------------------------` in the middle of the script.

You can find more information at the [Stack Apps Post](https://stackapps.com/q/6642/26088)

```
customSites['stackexchange.com'] = function(link, $obj) {
    if(link.indexOf('/users/') > -1) {
        var user_id = link.split('/')[4];
        $.getJSON("http://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/users/"+user_id+"/associated", function(json) {
            var oldestSiteUserId = json.items[0].user_id;
            var oldestSite = json.items[0].site_url.split('/')[2].split('.')[0];
            var oldestSiteRealName = json.items[0].site_name;
            
            $.getJSON("http://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/users/"+oldestSiteUserId+"?order=desc&sort=reputation&site="+oldestSite+"&filter=!9YdnSA07B", function(json2) {
                var display_name = json2.items[0].display_name,
                    location = json2.items[0].location,
                    image = json2.items[0].profile_image,
                    about = json2.items[0].about_me;
                var template = '<div class="onebox ob-user">\
                    <div class="user-gravatar64">\
                        <a href="http://stackexchange.com/users/'+user_id+'">\
                            <img height="64" width="64" alt="" src="'+image+'">\
                        </a>\
                    </div>\
                    <div>\
                        <img width="20" height="20" src="http://sstatic.net/stackexchange/img/apple-touch-icon.png" >\
                        <a class="ob-user-username" style="color: #4E82C2;" href="http://stackexchange.com/users/'+user_id+'">'+display_name+'</a>, '+location+'\
                    </div>\
                    <div style="overflow: auto;    height: 50px;">\
                        '+about+'\
                    </div>\
                 </div>';
                 
                 $obj.html(template);                
            });
        });        
    }
};
```